# Overlayed resources is not visible in spring boot web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've a simple question. I've used Spring Mvc legacy mode that runs using Servlet that was defined in web.xml, And now I've switched to use Spring boot. I've a dependency that overlayed to the project. After using Spring boot and bootstrap project using a launcher class and even with spring-boot:run, overlay's resources can not load in web server. How can I fix this problem?
that is my configurations:

```
<build>
    <finalName>swift</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <mainClass>path of Launcher</mainClass>
                        <finalName>swift</finalName>
                        <layout>WAR</layout>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my launcher :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class Launcher extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class);
    }

   ..........

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    // Only used when running in embedded servlet
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are using jar packaging. How the `maven-war-plugin` is supposed to do its thing if you're not using war packaging?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Packaging is jar

Comment: Well, war overlays are invoked with the `maven-war-plugin` which works with `war` packaging. You just can't do that.